# Number of bytes in encoded hex string

Tags: ruby, encoding, binary, hex

This is probably a simple question, but I'm trying to review encodings and bytes (which I haven't looked at in a while) to implement a binary protocol.

It looks like normal characters are 1 byte.  But when you encode them in Hex, it halves the number of bytes.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > "abcd".bytesize
 => 4 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > ["abcd"].pack("H*")
 => "\xAB\xCD" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > ["abcd"].pack("H*").bytesize
 => 2
```

I was also expecting the Hex encoding to come out with characters 0-9 and A-F

Can someone help clarify what is going on here?  And also if you can point me to a good review of encodings in general that is online I would love to brush up.  I haven't seen any simple overviews of this yet which would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: it appears that your actually decoding rather than encoding in hex as `abcd` (four bytes) in hex is `171, 205` (two bytes) decimal.

Comment: What do you want to do? Represent the code point of each character in hex notation?

Comment: A character is a byte. A hex digit [0-9A-F] is a nybble, or half a byte. For example, `FF` hex is the largest value of one byte. Therefore, your finding is to be expected: a 4-character string is 4 bytes, whereas `ABCD` hex is two bytes, `AB` and `CD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#pack` reads the given string and transforms it into binary according to the given format. `pack('H*')` means that the string you are giving represents hexadecimal notation, so it will convert the bytes `AB` and `CD` from hex into binary (`1010 1011 1100 1101`), which is two bytes.

Try `["g"].pack("H*")`, where `g` is not a valid hexadecimal character...

Comment: I think I see my confusion now - "abcd" was actually a hex string that it was converting to binary.  I thought I was taking a regular string and converting it to hex. :/  Thanks for the help!